# add xml namespace to child element

Tags: xml, oracle, namespaces

i wanted to added namespace to child element bt it is of no use.. 
i wanted the xml to look like this

final.xml

```
<sc:BusinessDataElementCatalog xmlns:sc="http://sctax.org/scits/oc-adapter">
  <sc:ScitsDataElementCatalog sc:Version="648" sc:ElementCount="18" sc:Created="2013-04-08T11:44:21" sc:CreatedBy="SYSTEM" sc:LastModified="2013-04-08T11:44:21" sc:ModifiedBy="SYSTEM">
    <sc:ScitsDataElement xmlns:sc="http://sctax.org/scits/oc-adapter" sc:Action="Add" sc:ElementDataSource="ITS" sc:ElementName="FrontNopaDataEntryDesc" sc:MultiLine="false" sc:ElementNamePrefix="its_" sc:ElementSource="ITS" sc:DataType="string" sc:Formatting="NotFormatted" sc:Shared="true" sc:Mandatory="false" sc:Editable="true" sc:MailTo="false" sc:ContextType="Entity" sc:ElementUse="ITS" sc:CaseEnabled="true" />
    <sc:ScitsDataElement xmlns:sc="http://sctax.org/scits/oc-adapter" sc:Action="Add" sc:ElementDataSource="ITS" sc:ElementName="FrontNopaGLAcctCode" sc:MultiLine="false" sc:ElementNamePrefix="its_" sc:ElementSource="ITS" sc:DataType="string" sc:Formatting="NotFormatted" sc:Shared="true" sc:Mandatory="false" sc:Editable="true" sc:MailTo="false" sc:ContextType="Entity" sc:ElementUse="ITS" sc:CaseEnabled="true" />
    <sc:ScitsDataElement xmlns:sc="http://sctax.org/scits/oc-adapter" sc:Action="Add" sc:ElementDataSource="ITS" sc:ElementName="FrontNopaDataEntryCode" sc:MultiLine="false" sc:ElementNamePrefix="its_" sc:ElementSource="ITS" sc:DataType="string" sc:Formatting="NotFormatted" sc:Shared="true" sc:Mandatory="false" sc:Editable="true" sc:MailTo="false" sc:ContextType="Entity" sc:ElementUse="ITS" sc:CaseEnabled="true" />
    <sc:ScitsDataElement xmlns:sc="http://sctax.org/scits/oc-adapter" sc:Action="Add" sc:ElementDataSource="ITS" sc:ElementName="FrontNopaGLAcctName" sc:MultiLine="false" sc:ElementNamePrefix="its_" sc:ElementSource="ITS" sc:DataType="string" sc:Formatting="NotFormatted" sc:Shared="true" sc:Mandatory="false" sc:Editable="true" sc:MailTo="false" sc:ContextType="Entity" sc:ElementUse="ITS" sc:CaseEnabled="true" />
    <sc:ScitsDataElement xmlns:sc="http://sctax.org/scits/oc-adapter" sc:Action="Add" sc:ElementDataSource="ITS" sc:ElementName="FrontJournalTypeSection" sc:MultiLine="false" sc:ElementNamePrefix="its_" sc:ElementSource="ITS" sc:DataType="string" sc:Formatting="NotFormatted" sc:Shared="true" sc:Mandatory="false" sc:Editable="true" sc:MailTo="false" sc:ContextType="Entity" sc:ElementUse="ITS" sc:CaseEnabled="true" />
    <sc:ScitsDataElement xmlns:sc="http://sctax.org/scits/oc-adapter" sc:Action="Add" sc:ElementDataSource="ITS" sc:ElementName="FrontNopaPenaltyAmount" sc:MultiLine="false" sc:ElementNamePrefix="its_" sc:ElementSource="ITS" sc:DataType="string" sc:Formatting="NotFormatted" sc:Shared="true" sc:Mandatory="false" sc:Editable="true" sc:MailTo="false" sc:ContextType="Entity" sc:ElementUse="ITS" sc:CaseEnabled="true" />      
  </sc:ScitsDataElementCatalog>
</sc:BusinessDataElementCatalog>
```

bt all i could manage is this xml
result.xml

```
<sc:BusinessDataElementCatalog  xmlns:sc="http://sctax.org/scits/oc-adapter">
  <sc:ScitsDataElementCatalog  sc:Version="648" sc:ElementCount="18" sc:Created="2013-04-08T11:44:21.000000" sc:CreatedBy="2013-04-08T11:44:21" sc:LastModified="2013-04-08T11:44:21.000000" sc:ModifiedBy="2013-04-08T11:44:21">
    <sc:ScitsDataElement sc:Action="Add" sc:ElementDataSource="ITS" sc:ElementName="BackNopaTotBalance" sc:MultiLine="false" sc:ElementNamePrefix="its_" sc:ElementSource="ITS" sc:DataType="string" sc:Formatting="NotFormatted" sc:Shared="true" sc:Mandatory="false" sc:Editable="true" sc:MailTo="false" sc:ContextType="Entity" sc:ElementUse="ITS" sc:CaseEnabled="true">
  </sc:ScitsDataElement>
    <sc:ScitsDataElement sc:Action="Add" sc:ElementDataSource="ITS" sc:ElementName="BackNopaTotPmntsCredits" sc:MultiLine="false" sc:ElementNamePrefix="its_" sc:ElementSource="ITS" sc:DataType="string" sc:Formatting="NotFormatted" sc:Shared="true" sc:Mandatory="false" sc:Editable="true" sc:MailTo="false" sc:ContextType="Entity" sc:ElementUse="ITS" sc:CaseEnabled="true">
  </sc:ScitsDataElement>
    <sc:ScitsDataElement sc:Action="Add" sc:ElementDataSource="ITS" sc:ElementName="BackNopaTotLiability" sc:MultiLine="false" sc:ElementNamePrefix="its_" sc:ElementSource="ITS" sc:DataType="string" sc:Formatting="NotFormatted" sc:Shared="true" sc:Mandatory="false" sc:Editable="true" sc:MailTo="false" sc:ContextType="Entity" sc:ElementUse="ITS" sc:CaseEnabled="true">
  </sc:ScitsDataElement>
    <sc:ScitsDataElement sc:Action="Add" sc:ElementDataSource="ITS" sc:ElementName="BackPeriodEndDateSection" sc:MultiLine="false" sc:ElementNamePrefix="its_" sc:ElementSource="ITS" sc:DataType="string" sc:Formatting="NotFormatted" sc:Shared="true" sc:Mandatory="false" sc:Editable="true" sc:MailTo="false" sc:ContextType="Entity" sc:ElementUse="ITS" sc:CaseEnabled="true">
  </sc:ScitsDataElement>
    <sc:ScitsDataElement sc:Action="Add" sc:ElementDataSource="ITS" sc:ElementName="BackNopaGLAcctName" sc:MultiLine="false" sc:ElementNamePrefix="its_" sc:ElementSource="ITS" sc:DataType="string" sc:Formatting="NotFormatted" sc:Shared="true" sc:Mandatory="false" sc:Editable="true" sc:MailTo="false" sc:ContextType="Entity" sc:ElementUse="ITS" sc:CaseEnabled="true">
  </sc:ScitsDataElement>
    <sc:ScitsDataElement sc:Action="Add" sc:ElementDataSource="ITS" sc:ElementName="BackNopaDataEntryCode" sc:MultiLine="false" sc:ElementNamePrefix="its_" sc:ElementSource="ITS" sc:DataType="string" sc:Formatting="NotFormatted" sc:Shared="true" sc:Mandatory="false" sc:Editable="true" sc:MailTo="false" sc:ContextType="Entity" sc:ElementUse="ITS" sc:CaseEnabled="true">
  </sc:ScitsDataElement>        
</sc:ScitsDataElementCatalog >
</sc:BusinessDataElementCatalog >
```

and this is my query

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("sc:BusinessDataElementCatalog ", 
XMLATTRIBUTES('http://sctax.org/scits/oc-adapter' AS "xmlns:sc") 
, B.XML )
FROM
    (SELECT 
        XMLELEMENT ("sc:ScitsDataElementCatalog " , 
        XMLATTRIBUTES( MAX(C.REVISION) AS "sc:Version" , 
        COUNT(*) AS "sc:ElementCount" , 
        MIN(C.CREATED_DTTM) AS "sc:Created", 
        '2013-04-08T11:44:21' AS "sc:CreatedBy" , 
        MAX(C.UPDATED_DTTM) AS "sc:LastModified" , 
        '2013-04-08T11:44:21' AS "sc:ModifiedBy" ) ,
            XMLAGG(
                XMLELEMENT("sc:ScitsDataElement", 
                    XMLATTRIBUTES ('http://sctax.org/scits/oc-adapter' AS "xmlns:sc",
                      CASE
                        WHEN ( CATALOG.version_on_insert > 630 )
                        THEN 'Add'
                        ELSE 'Update'
                      END AS "sc:Action" , 
                      DATASOURCE.CODE AS "sc:ElementDataSource", 
                      CATALOG.ELEMENT_NAME AS "sc:ElementName" ,
                      CASE
                        WHEN ( CATALOG.multiline_flag = 1 )
                        THEN 'true'
                        ELSE 'false'
                      END AS "sc:MultiLine" , 
                      'its_' AS "sc:ElementNamePrefix" , 
                      DATASOURCE.CODE AS "sc:ElementSource" , 
                      LOWER(DATATYPE.CODE) AS "sc:DataType" , 
                      FORMATTYPE.CODE AS "sc:Formatting"  ,
                        CASE 
                           WHEN ( CATALOG.shared_element_flag = 1 ) THEN 'true'
                      ELSE 'false'
                         END as "sc:Shared"  ,
                      CASE 
                           WHEN ( CATALOG.mandatory_flag = 1 ) THEN 'true'
                      ELSE 'false'
                         END as "sc:Mandatory"  ,
                      CASE 
                           WHEN ( CATALOG.editable_flag = 1 ) THEN 'true'
                      ELSE 'false'
                         END as "sc:Editable"  ,
                      CASE 
                           WHEN ( CATALOG.mail_to_flag = 1 ) THEN 'true'
                      ELSE 'false'
                         END as "sc:MailTo"  ,
                      context.code as "sc:ContextType"  ,
                      'ITS' as "sc:ElementUse"  ,
                      CASE 
                           WHEN ( CATALOG.case_enabled_flag = 1 ) THEN 'true'
                      ELSE 'false'
                         END AS "sc:CaseEnabled"  ,
                      CATALOG.default_value as "sc:DefaultValue"
                      )
                  )
              )
          )AS xml
    FROM ITS_OC_DATA_ELEMENT_CATALOG CATALOG
    JOIN ITS_OC_DATA_ELEMENT_CATALOG C
    ON c.OC_DATA_ELEMENT_CATALOG_KEY=CATALOG.OC_DATA_ELEMENT_CATALOG_KEY
    JOIN r_oc_element_datasource dataSource
    ON CATALOG.oc_element_datasource_key = dataSource.oc_element_datasource_key
    JOIN r_oc_element_datatype datatype
    ON CATALOG.oc_element_datatype_key = datatype.oc_element_datatype_key
    JOIN r_oc_context_type context
    ON CATALOG.oc_context_type_key = context.oc_context_type_key
    JOIN r_oc_text_format_type formatType
    ON CATALOG.OC_TEXT_FORMAT_TYPE_KEY = FORMATTYPE.OC_TEXT_FORMAT_TYPE_KEY
    WHERE CATALOG.REVISION             > 630
    ) B ;
```

is it possible for **sc:ScitsDataElement** to have namespace..how can i acchieve it in this query..